# Is there a name for the feeling "Damn, I already asked this question three years ago"?

Tags: phrase-requests

[I'll copy from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119584/what-do-you-call-the-feeling-of-damn-i-asked-this-three-years-ago):

I admit I'm sometimes [too quick with the gun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119584/what-do-you-call-the-feeling-of-damn-i-asked-this-three-years-ago) when firing away questions.

Does the feeling "Damn, I just asked this now, and I see it's a dup of a question I asked three years ago" have a name?

Preemptive word for the smart: "Lazy" is a good term for the asker, but not for the feeling.

Comment: Tagging suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you check if you asked this question already?

Comment: @Kris - good one :)

Comment: Vaguely related: in [The Meaning of Liff](http://folk.uio.no/alied/TMoL.html), the definition of Woking is "Standing in the kitchen wondering what you came in here for".

Comment: I think it's called 'Doh!'

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to flag this question as a repeat.

Comment: I think that this question is too localized to meet our standards. Also, you haven't really even given an approximation of how it makes you feel (angry, empowered, stupid, awkward, proud, titillated?), or offered any guidance on why certain words you have thought of don't meet your criteria.  Therefore, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: deja Q?       Sorry.  I'll go now.

Answer (score 2):

I offer the term [déjà vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu). Though not literally true, it captures the spirit.

Comment: The term _déjà vu_ refers to the feeling when one feels like he is experiencing something for the second time (but not sure why). I don't think the asker meant this.

Comment: @Meysam: It literally means "Seen already", which is an accurate (but not complete) description of what is happening.

Comment: @Marcin It means that in French, but this is an English forum.

Comment: @Pitarou: It is so understood also in English.

Comment: It's not really Deja vu. Deja vu, for me, is when I have two moments in the space-time continuum that feel as if they're the same moment. Both the earlier and later moments would have to include this feeling to be really identical. In my case, I only experience this feeling on the later moment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[chagrin](http://dictionary.reference.com/wordoftheday/archive/2002/06/05.html)* is the word you are looking for.

> **chagrin** \shuh-GRIN\, noun:
>   1. Acute vexation, annoyance, or embarrassment, arising from disappointment or failure.

Comment: I removed the tag america-english, I just didn't know what to tag this.

Comment: @ripper234, thanks; I've removed the reference from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something as simple as- **memory lapse**!

Or probably the sentiment could be described as **feeling sheepish**, **discomfiture, vexation, chagrin**.

If you want to put it light-heartedly, you could say, *you are **mortified** at your temporary amnesia.*